# ¿Por qué se escribe "r" a principio de palabra aunque el sonido sea "rr"?

Tags: ortografía, historia, letras

He intentado plantear esta pregunta de varias formas. Primero me preguntaba por qué la "rr" no había sido nunca incluida en el abecedario, si representa un sonido diferente de la "r". Según [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4131/12637) es por la regla de que a principio de palabra se escribe "r" aunque el sonido sea "rr", que hace que no pueda haber una sección en el diccionario conteniendo las palabras que empiezan por "rr" al no haber ninguna (a diferencia de lo que pasaba con la "ll" antes de que la eliminasen del abecedario).

Así que derivo mi pregunta hacia esta otra: ¿cuál es el origen de esa regla? Buscando el término de búsqueda "rr*" en el CORDE encontramos casos en el siglo XIV (*rrey*, *rreyna*, *rreçibió*, *rricos*), en el siglo XV (*rregla*, *rrazonable*, *rruego*), siglo XVI (*rresolviere*, *rrazon*, *rregidor*, *rrotas*), siglo XVII (*rrabia*, *rrodillas*, *rreverenzia*) e incluso algunas en el siglo XVIII, aunque cada vez menos.

Lo mismo aplica a la "r" después de consonante: *honrra*, *Isrrael* y *alrrededor* aparecen en textos de la época del Quijote.

En algún momento tuvo que venir la RAE o quien fuera y poner orden, porque las formas con una sola "r" también se daban y desde antiguo. Así pues, ¿cuándo se consolidó en el idioma español la norma de usar "r" aunque el sonido fuera "rr" a principio de palabra y tras consonante? ¿A qué se debía que se usaran ambas formas? (Ejemplo: *rey* y *rrey* convivieron hasta el siglo XVII.) ¿Tal vez dependía de los dialectos regionales?

---

**Caso de estudio: *rey* vs *rrey***

```
siglo   rey     rrey
----------------------
XII     739     0
XIII    17708   2371
XIV     28918   17175
XV      37828   21433
XVI     89233   4168
XVII    21873   744
XVIII   4321    4
```

Comment: Apostaría a que, con la normalización de la ortografía en el siglo XVIII, se decidió que era mejor reservar la *rr* para aquellos casos en que era necesario marcar cuál era el sonido de la *r*. Como a principio de palabra o tras *l*, *n* o *s* no hay duda (siempre es el sonido fuerte), no hacía falta. Me parece similar al caso de la *g* oclusiva; solo ponemos *gu-* cuando va seguida de *e* o *i*, porque ahí la letra puede tener dos sonidos diferentes, pero no en los demás casos porque no hay ambigüedad en cuanto al posible sonido.

Comment: ¿Alguna idea de cuál es era la frecuencia de uso de *rr* inicial comparada con *r*? ¿Son 50% de los casos, 10%, unos pocos...? Sin una norma firme y una población con alta competencia de escritura estas cosas suceden, me imagino.

Comment: @pablodf76 lo he intentado pero si buscas "rr*" en el CORDE, debería devolverte solo casos de "rr" a principio de palabra, pero te devuelve también "tórrido" porque la búsqueda considera las letras con acento como separadores de palabra (como los guiones). Y así cuesta trabajo hacer cuentas. Buscando palabras completas, por ejemplo "rey" aparece unas 37000 veces en textos del siglo XV, por más de 21000 casos de "rrey". Si nos vamos al siglo XVI son 89000 de "rey" por 4000 de "rrey".

Answer (score 3):

Aclaremos, en primer lugar, que *r* y *rr* eran históricamente variantes del mismo fonema en su forma corta y larga. Ése era ciertamente el caso en latín tardío, cuando todavía existían consonantes geminadas (dobles), analizables como formas con un contraste de cantidad (el mismo que diferenciaba vocales cortas y largas). No sabemos con seguridad cómo se pronunciaba la *r* en latín pero los expertos creen que pudo haber sido una vibrante múltiple, como nuestra *rr*, siendo la *rr* latina una versión más larga.

Una hipótesis de por qué la *r* inicial pasó a pronunciarse como *rr* es la siguiente. En el paso del latín al romance ibérico, entre vocales las consonantes geminadas latinas tendieron a simplificarse mientras que las simples se [debilitaban](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenici%C3%B3n) (/t/ > /d/ y /tt/ > /t/). Esto no ocurrió en comienzo de palabra, donde las consonantes permanecieron "fuertes". Este desplazamiento hizo que se identificase la articulación *fortis* en comienzo de palabra con las antiguas geminadas, ya simplificadas; o sea, los hablantes pasaron a identificar la /p/ inicial de *palma* "palma" con la /p/ medial de *cippus* "cepo" (ahora acortada) en vez de con la antigua /p/ medial de *opera*, que había pasado a ser una /b/ ("obra"). Este fenómeno arrastró a la vibrante alveolar /r/: así, toda /r/ inicial se reforzó para identificarse con la /rr/ medial.

En castellano este proceso no involucró otras consonantes; en catalán y asturleonés, por ejemplo, ocurrió con las /l/ iniciales (latín *luna* > *lluna*), y ciertos dialectos, con las /n/ iniciales (dando *ñ*). Aquí la marca de fortificación fue la palatalización.

¿Qué tiene que ver esto con la ortografía? Que los cambios fonéticos suelen despistar bastante a los escribas por su naturaleza gradual. Sin una institución normalizadora de la ortografía ni medios de comunicación eficaces, los escribas vacilan entre las alternativas disponibles para transcribir lo que oyen. De hecho, estas vacilaciones y errores son una de las fuentes más útiles para documentar cambios fonéticos en curso.

Un problema es que la vacilación ortográfica que aparece documentada es bastante tardía. Las geminadas latinas se simplificaron hacia el final del período del latín vulgar (s. VIII d.C.), no después, como se deriva del hecho de que existen todavía al sur de la [Línea Massa-Senigallia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_Massa-Senigallia). Pero precisamente porque no hay una autoridad que diga "esto ya no es latín sino castellano, con tales y cuales normas", las vacilaciones pueden continuar durante siglos, si el escriba trata de escribir según la norma clásica. Así se pueden ver en el CORDE ejemplos hasta en el siglo XVI de palabras con *cc* cuyo origen es una geminada latina, como *bocca*, *peccado* y *occupar*; con *pp* como *approbar* y *opportuno*, etc.

Es por otra parte raro ver en castellano una consonante doble (escrita) en comienzo de palabra, pero quizá *ll-* y *rr-* se reforzaron mutuamente por un tiempo. Luego fue sólo cuestión de tiempo y sentido común para que la convención restaurara la *r* escrita simple inicial.

Comment: es importante señalar que en italiano, sorpresivamente para los que hablamos español, la /r/ inicial no es una vibrante múltiple sino una vibrante simple, eso también podría usarse para decir que en latín tardío itálico /r/ no se pronuncaiba como vibrante múltiple.